# Tensorflow switch case in batch dimension with Conv2d

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

Suppose I have a batch with shape [n, h, w, c] as well as a list of n indices in range of 0-9 and 10 Conv2D `convs`, that I want to apply to the data depending on the index in the list. The indices list changes with every batch.

Eg. with input x, batch size 4 and indices l=[1,5,1,9] I would like to compute `[convs[l[0]](x[0]), convs[l[1]](x[1]), convs[l[2]](x[2]), convs[l[3]](x[3])]`

A naive solution would be to compute every combination and gather based on `l`. However, this requires 10 times the amount of memory. Is there a better solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

One "hacky" solution would be to expand the dimension of the input from `[n, h, w, c]` to `[1, n, h, w, c]`, then use `Conv3D` instead with kernel shape `[1, x, y]`

If you have the weights defined separately (weights can also be obtained using `layer.weights`), you could similarly stack them in the 0th dimension and use them through `tf.nn.conv3d`.

Comment: Hi, but that would not allow dynamically selecting the kernels based on the indices list, right?

Comment: You will have to use `tf.unstack` to get individual kernels.